# Get all combinations

Tags: vba, excel, combinatorics

I would like to generate all possible vectors where minimum and maximum of each element is known and some set of elements can have only the same value.

For example I have an input like this:

```
rid Set MaxId
1     a     1
2     b     2
3     c     2
4     c     2
5     c     2
```

Set identifies elements which all should always have the same value, `MaxId` identifies maximum integer atribute can have, minimum is always 1. From this data, we can create the following 4 combinations (denoted `c1` - `c4`):

```
rid Set c1  c2  c3  c4
1   a   1   1   1   1
2   b   1   1   2   2
3   c   1   2   1   2
4   c   1   2   1   2
5   c   1   2   1   2
```

How can I do this using VBA? In my real data I have 100 rows with 5 different sets, resulting in total 80 variables where max Id is ranging between 1 and 5.

The example above is complete, there is no additional input to be provided. Let's consider different example:

```
rid Set MaxId
1     a     2
2     b     1
3     c     3
4     c     3
5     c     3
```

This would result in 6 possible combinations (`2 x 1 x 3`). There is only one `3` as this number is part of what I call "a set", identified by same letter `c`. The possible combinations are:

```
rid Set c1  c2  c3  c4 c5 c6
1   a   1   2   1   1   2  2
2   b   1   1   1   1   1  1
3   c   1   1   2   3   2  3
4   c   1   1   2   3   2  3
5   c   1   1   2   3   2  3
```

Comment: What logic is used to decided whether a MaxId=2 results in '1 1 2 2' instead of '1 2 1 2'?

Comment: @AugustoMen When there is the same set, than all elements in the set have same values. This means that rows 3-5 can have either values `1,1,1` or `2,2,2`. Second row can have either 1 or 2, first row is always equal to 1. From these known inputs I would like to generate all combinations (`c1-c4`). Is this any clearer now?

Comment: What if MaxID = 3? What does that need to produce?

Comment: I don't understand why rows 3,4,5 are identical. could you put more of the actual input file up instead of the top 5 rows?  This sounds like a fun challenge.

Comment: @PJRosenburg Rows 3,4,5 are always identical, because they are part of a set. Within one set, all number are always identical. I added another example, hope it gets more clear. There is no `max Id` 5, every set has its own `max Id1`.

Comment: why doesn't set "a" have 2 rows if it has a max of two?  It just seems like the extra rows to repeat the same information from row 3 doesn't make sense to me.  I can understand the sets, the different combinations, just not what makes you print out more lines of the same information in set c but not set a, for example.

Comment: @PJRosenburg There is no relation between `Max ID` and number of rows set has. Number of rows and set identification is fixed input for me. `Max Id` is a variable I configure. Based on this I would like to generate combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, then I would call your "sets" dimensions and your combinations possible addresses in those dimensions. For example in two dimensions x and y where x is in length 2 and y is in length 3 there are 6 possible points(x,y) if x and y elements of N. In three dimensions x, y and z where x is in length 2, y is in length 3 and z is in length 2 there are 12 possible points(x,y,z) if x, y and z elements of N.

For going through all addresses in dimensions normally nested loops are used. So I would do this here also.

[image]

```
Sub Dimensions()

 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

  'create a dictionary for up to 5 different dimensions named "a" to "e"
  'and their max length values
  'using dictionary because mapping key (dimension name) to value (max length value)
  Set dDimensions = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  dDimensions.Add "a", 9999 '9999 is the stop value which shows that this Dimension is not used
  dDimensions.Add "b", 9999
  dDimensions.Add "c", 9999
  dDimensions.Add "d", 9999
  dDimensions.Add "e", 9999

  'get the dimension definitions from A2:B[n]
  r = 2
  Do While .Cells(r, 1) <> ""
   sDimension = .Cells(r, 1).Value
   lMax = .Cells(r, 2).Value
   If lMax > 0 And dDimensions.exists(sDimension) Then
    'if inconsistent definitions for length of dimensions exists,
    'for example "a" with max length 3 and "a" with max length 2,
    'then take the lowest max length definition, in example "a" with 2
    If dDimensions.Item(sDimension) > lMax Then dDimensions.Item(sDimension) = lMax
   End If
   r = r + 1
  Loop

  'calculate the count of possible combinations
  lCount = 1
  For Each sDimension In dDimensions
   lMax = dDimensions.Item(sDimension)
   If lMax < 9999 Then lCount = lCount * lMax
  Next

  'create a dictionary for the results
  'up to 5 different Dimensions named "a" to "e"
  'and their possible values in lCount possible combinations
  Set dResults = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim aPointAddresses() As Long
  ReDim aPointAddresses(lCount - 1)
  dResults.Add "a", aPointAddresses
  dResults.Add "b", aPointAddresses
  dResults.Add "c", aPointAddresses
  dResults.Add "d", aPointAddresses
  dResults.Add "e", aPointAddresses

  'go through all possible addresses and fill the dResults
  lCount = 0
  For a = 1 To dDimensions.Item("a")
   For b = 1 To dDimensions.Item("b")
    For c = 1 To dDimensions.Item("c")
     For d = 1 To dDimensions.Item("d")
      For e = 1 To dDimensions.Item("e")

       If dDimensions.Item("a") < 9999 Then
        arr = dResults.Item("a")
        arr(lCount) = a
        dResults.Item("a") = arr
       End If

       If dDimensions.Item("b") < 9999 Then
        arr = dResults.Item("b")
        arr(lCount) = b
        dResults.Item("b") = arr
       End If

       If dDimensions.Item("c") < 9999 Then
        arr = dResults.Item("c")
        arr(lCount) = c
        dResults.Item("c") = arr
       End If

       If dDimensions.Item("d") < 9999 Then
        arr = dResults.Item("d")
        arr(lCount) = d
        dResults.Item("d") = arr
       End If

       If dDimensions.Item("e") < 9999 Then
        arr = dResults.Item("e")
        arr(lCount) = e
        dResults.Item("e") = arr
       End If

       lCount = lCount + 1

       If dDimensions.Item("e") = 9999 Then Exit For
      Next
      If dDimensions.Item("d") = 9999 Then Exit For
     Next
     If dDimensions.Item("c") = 9999 Then Exit For
    Next
    If dDimensions.Item("b") = 9999 Then Exit For
   Next
   If dDimensions.Item("a") = 9999 Then Exit For
  Next

  'now dResults contains an array of possible point addresses for each used dimension
  'key:="dimension", item:={p1Addr, p2Addr, p3Addr, ..., pNAddr}

  'clear the result range
  .Range("D:XFD").Clear

  'print out the results in columns D:XFD
  .Range("D1").Value = "p1"
  .Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("D1:XFD1")

  r = 2
  Do While .Cells(r, 1) <> ""
   sDimension = .Cells(r, 1).Value
   arr = dResults.Item(sDimension)
   .Range(.Cells(r, 4), .Cells(r, 4 + UBound(arr))).Value = arr
   r = r + 1
  Loop

 End With

End Sub
```